# Crear "Checkout Preferences" con varios Items. Node SDK

Tags: mercadopago

Buenas, alguno utilizo el post a "/checkout/preferences" desde el sdk de node, con algo como:

```html
var preference = {
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Producto1",
                "quantity": 1,
                "currency_id": "ARS",
                "unit_price": 10
            },
            {
                "title": "Producto2",
                "quantity": 1,
                "currency_id": "ARS",
                "unit_price": 20
            }
        ]
    };

mp.createPreference (preference);
```

Al enviar eso, me toma correctamente la suma del checkout, pero solamente con el titulo del 1er item.

Yo espero redireccionar a mp y listar los detalles items agregados al carrito.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Hola, pudiste solucionar? Estoy con la misma inquietud.

Comment: @Babblo, Aun no pude solucionarlo, cuando tenga novedades actualizo el post, Saludos.

Comment: Buenas ami igual me pasa... pero creo que mercado pago no realiza facturación de n cantidad de productos.. osea varios titulos de n productos.. solo toma el monto que se va sumando..